# Count number of users while login authentication

Tags: java, count

I am new to java and here I faced a problem.

I have a login application in my project and I want to count the number of users that are accessing my project by login authentication.

How can I know the number of users(50, 100....etc) in each day let's say.
How can I see total number of users from a specific date up to now those have accessed my project by login? For example, let's say person A logged in and count will be 1, then person B logged in then count will be 2.

I'm using Java with an Oracle database, on Windows XP.

Comment: What programming language? What database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the users are in a database, you could keep track of each time a specific user logs in, and then just sum all of those columns to get the total number of logins.

Comment: Hii...No no users can be from anywhere, while logged in how count value will be automatically incremented? If count value will be automatically incremented then only I can send the count value to my database and in my database i can see total number of users. Please help me

Comment: @sujit, Lainlwakura means: you should add a row each time a user logs in which has the user ID and that date/time for example. You don't have to store the count because the count is the same as the number of rows in the table. You can even select rows from a certain day and count those.

Comment: Hii...I have another doubt, Can I know the geographic locations all over world from where users are accessing my login page? For example if a person accessed from Newyork then the geographic location will be displayed as NY or like that. How it is possible? Plz help me friends..

Comment: This is a much more complex topic, I'd create another question for it if I was you (I don't know much about it).

Comment: ohk...ya it is a very complex topic.....I am trying to find the solution by creating another question.